# How justify that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$ is a transcendental number

Tags: gamma-function, transcendental-numbers

Let $\Gamma(x)$ the Gamma function. See, if you need its definiton, for example in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

While I was evaluating an integral with the help of Wolfram Alpha, I have known that $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$ is a transcendental number.

> **Question.** What's the reasoning to know this fact, that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$ is a trancendental number?  **Thanks in advance.**

I presume that it is consequence of a theorem or computational method based on the definition of transcendental numbers, and that the Gamma function is a factorial. How justify that previous real number is trascendental?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) claims that $\Gamma(x)$ is transcendental for $x=\frac16,\frac14,\frac13,\frac23,\frac34,\frac56$ and that they are algebraically independent from $\pi$ (unlike $\Gamma(1/2)$)

Comment: Many thanks @SimplyBeautifulArt I am going to wait if some user want provide more details. I didn't read Wikipedia's claim. My thoughts were that should be an easy consequence of some proposition. Any case I hope that some user tell us what about it, if it is a difficult question or can be deduced from the standard theory.

Comment: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/PerspectiveMath1984 is a survey of transcendentality proofs.

Comment: Many thanks @Chappers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631639/upper-bound-on-integral-int-1-infty-fracdx-sqrtx3-1-4/1631760?sfb%3D2#1631760) the identity

> $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) = {\frac{2^{\frac{14}{9}}\cdot 3^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot \pi^{\frac{5}{6}} }{\text{AGM}\left(1+\sqrt{3},\sqrt{8}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}\tag{1}$$

is proved. The trascendence of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$ then follows from recalling classical results (Theorem $7$ [here](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TranscendencePeriods.pdf)) about the trascendence of periods / complete elliptic integrals.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I am going to study it, also the literaterature.